# Variables inside and outside of a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

The question itself lies inside the code (or questions themselves *lie*, since there are several question marks).

Code:

```
i = -3  # Where am I? Am I not the 'i' that should be inside the for loop?
print("before the cycle:", i)
for i in range(5):  # Why am I starting from 0, not from -3?
    print("cycle variable:", i)
    i += 1  # How come I change nothing in terms of amount of loop iterations?
    print("(?) variable:", i)  # And why do I start from the same 0?
```

Output:

```
before the cycle: -3
cycle variable: 0
(?) variable: 1
cycle variable: 1
(?) variable: 2
cycle variable: 2
(?) variable: 3
cycle variable: 3
(?) variable: 4
cycle variable: 4
(?) variable: 5
```

Where should I look up the information about such variable behavior?

My guess is that the question about loop start is somehow related to LEGB rule, and `i` is both declared and defined (?!) right after `for` keyword.

But again, I seek knowledge, not guesses.

Comment: `range(5)` emits the numbers 0 (inclusive) to 5 (exclusive). It is not affected by the prior value of the variable `i`, nor by you reassigning `i` during the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions boil down to the mechanics of *generators*:

```
for i in range(5):  # Why am I starting from 0, not from -3?
```

In this line, the *range(5)* is a generator that will produce values: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, sequentially. Even if you changed the value of *i* before the for loop, or you will change the value of *i* inside the for loop, the for loop will take the next value from the generator and will execute until the generator raises *StopIteration*, which basically means that it ran out of values to generate.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken for the functionality of `range`. It is a sequence generator which starts with `0` by default and hence it produces 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 for `range(5)`.

If you want to step from -3 in 5 steps you could do :

```
i = -3
range(i, i+5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've understood more or less correctly. "for i" assigns the items yielded by the range generator to i. "range(5)" defaults to a range from 0 to 5. You could add a second parameter, for instance

range(-3, 5)

Or if you want to iterate from a number stored in an earlier variable, you could give it a different name, and pass it as the first argument:

x = 2

for i in range(x, 5):